# Apache Commons UrlValidator NoClassDefFound on Android

Tags: android, apache-commons, url-validation

In an Android app, I recently started using Apache's `UrlValidator` class to validate Urls.  Everything works great!  However, once the first round of beta testing began, I've received this crash from a few users:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator

`UrlValidator` is included normally in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.0'
```

What's going on here?  This works completely fine on all the nexus devices I own.  The crashes from beta testers were from a Droid Razr HD, a galaxy Tab 2 and a Galaxy S4, all running Android 4.x.

My hunch is that Samsung/Motorola customized something in the OS that has something to do with the commons library.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `NoClassDefFoundError`s were happening because multidex was only partially implemented in this app - for some reason, this works fine on Android 5/6 but on Android 4.x it makes your app crash with `NoClassDefFoundError` in random places.  It seems to me like this situation should be detected by Android Studio and you should be warned you've improperly implemented multidex support.

To fix it, make sure the following is true for your project:

1. `multiDexEnabled = true` in the `defaultConfig` section of your app-level build.gradle
2. `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in your project-level build.gradle
3. Call `MultiDex.install()` in `attachBaseContext()` of your Application class.

More details on multidex can be found [here.](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)